# String to term, if no term exists - catching error

Tags: haskell

Working on task, implementing error messages for different situations.. Bit stuck on converting string to term, if there is no defined term.

Here is my program:

```
readPhone :: String->String->String->Phone
readPhone typee countrycode phoneno
    |head(countrycode)=='+'=error "+ found"
    |typee==""=error "Missing phone type"
    |otherwise=makePhone (stringToTerm typee) (toCountryCode(read countrycode)) (toPhoneNo(read phoneno))

stringToTerm :: String  -> PhoneType
stringToTerm stringEvent = read $ stringEvent ++ " " 

scanStringCC :: String -> CountryCode
scanStringCC x = if all (`elem` "0123456789") x
                 then read x :: CountryCode
                 else 0





data PhoneType = WorkLandline|PrivateMobile|WorkMobile|Other deriving (Read,Show,Eq)

newtype PlainString = PlainString String
instance Show PlainString where
  show (PlainString s) = s
--instance Num Int where
--   (*)=int_times
--   (+)=int_plus

data CountryCode = CountryCode
    {
        cCode :: Integer
    } deriving (Eq,Read)

instance Show CountryCode where
    show (CountryCode a)=(show (PlainString "+")) ++ (show a)
instance Num CountryCode where 
    CountryCode a * CountryCode b = CountryCode (a * b)
    CountryCode a + CountryCode b = CountryCode (a + b)
    CountryCode a - CountryCode b = CountryCode (a - b)
    fromInteger x = CountryCode (fromInteger x)

toCountryCode :: Integer->CountryCode
toCountryCode ccode  
    | ccode<0=error "Negative country code"
    |otherwise = CountryCode ccode


data PhoneNo = PhoneNo
    {
        pNo :: Integer
    } deriving (Read,Eq)
instance Show PhoneNo where
    show (PhoneNo a)=show a
instance Num PhoneNo where
    PhoneNo a + PhoneNo b=PhoneNo(a+b)
    PhoneNo a - PhoneNo b=PhoneNo(a-b)
    PhoneNo a * PhoneNo b=PhoneNo(a*b)
    fromInteger x = PhoneNo (fromInteger x)

toPhoneNo :: Integer -> PhoneNo
toPhoneNo pno  
    | pno<0=error "Negative phone number"
    |otherwise = PhoneNo pno

data Phone = Phone
    {
        phoneType :: PhoneType,
        countryCode :: CountryCode,
        phoneNo :: PhoneNo
    } deriving (Read,Eq)
instance Show Phone where
    show (Phone a b c)=show b ++ (show (PlainString " ")) ++ show c ++(show (PlainString "(")) ++ show a ++ (show (PlainString ")"))

makePhone :: PhoneType -> CountryCode  -> PhoneNo -> Phone
makePhone phonetype countrycode phoneno
    |otherwise = Phone phonetype countrycode phoneno
```

Works fine for `readPhone "Other" "358" "2"` or `readPhone "" "358" "2"` (last one gives **"Missing phone type"** error, which is correct

However, if I give `readPhone "notexist "358" "2"`, it says **+358 2(--- Exception: Prelude.read: no parse**

How do I catch it to show proper error code: **"Incorrect phone type"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `stringToTerm` function uses the `read` function to parse the PhoneType, this will fail with the error you are getting when it can't parse the type.
If you want to handle this situation yourself you should use the `readMaybe` and handle the returned `Maybe` :

```
stringToTerm :: String -> PhoneType
stringToTerm stringEvent = case readMaybe stringEvent of 
  Just phoneType -> phoneType 
  Nothing -> error "Incorrect phone type"
```

Using errors to signal validation failures is not very idiomatic Haskell, I think a better way would be to change the signature of the `readPhone` function to

```
readPhone :: String -> String -> String -> Either String Phone
```

and return `Left "error message"` for validation failures and `Right phone` in the successful case.

Comment: Thank you sir! Find Haskell amusing, but didnt read any of materials, figuring things myself. However giving errors was a part of a task, ie cant do it any other way.